# Using an external UITableViewDelegate and calling back to a UINavigation controller through a UIViewController

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have UINavigation Controller that has a UIViewController pushed onto the stack and displayed.

That UIViewController has a UITableView and uses an external class for that UITableView's datasource and delegate. I do this because I need to swap that datasource dynamically. Everything works beautifully for displaying data.

However, when handling `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` "down" in the delegate
I'm struggling with the proper way to call all the way back to the UINavigationController. Whereas I'm used to being able to do something like this when the UIViewController and Delegates are the same object:

```
ExampleViewController *newViewController = [[ExampleViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:newViewController animated:YES];
[newViewController release];
```

I cannot do so from the delegate and I'm just not getting what the correct reference back to the UINavigationController should be is the pushViewController.

Do I need to set an ID similar to a delegate so that the UITableViewDelegate has a pointer directly back to the UINavigationController?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only UIViewController instances that have been pushed onto a navigation stack have convenient access to a corresponding UINavigationController instance through the "navigationController" property. So you have a couple of options:

1) Pass a reference to the navigation controller to your table view delegate(s) so they can call the "push" method you're used to using.

2) Pass a reference to your view controller to your table view delegate(s), and have them call a method when a user taps a table view row. You can write your own delegate protocol and implement it in your view controller to formalize this approach.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback. I used method 1 and just have a retained UINavigationController property that I set when I designate it as the datasource and delegate. It seems a bit excessive to roll a protocol for this but maybe I'm just being lazy since that would for sure be less tightly coupled.

Comment: Sounds good to me. You can always refactor your code later if need be - in the meantime, your code will be trimmer and easier to maintain.